# Neat framework not installing

Tags: bash, rubygems, bourbon, neat

I'm trying to install bourbon/neat in a non rails project.

I followed the simple instructions found here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/neat#installation

But as you can see **Bash does not recognize the gem.**

I tried restarting Terminal, but nothing new happened.

(I've already installed bourbon the exact same way and it worked OK)

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Andre-2:site abarro$ gem install neat -v 1.5.1
Fetching: sass-3.2.19.gem (100%)
Successfully installed sass-3.2.19
Fetching: neat-1.5.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed neat-1.5.1
2 gems installed
MacBook-Pro-de-Andre-2:site abarro$ neat install
-bash: neat: command not found
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: it would be a major failing for an installer to report that a gem was successfully installed when it wasn't. Its most likely that `neat` got installed to a directory that is not in your PATH. So use `find /path/to/root/of/ruby -name 'neat'`. Hopefully that will show you what dir it is in, then add that dir to your path. ALSO, as there aren't that many followers for the `gems` tag, best to add a `ruby` tag. Good luck.

Comment: Had to fix my RVM installation. Added    [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function* to my bash_profile

Comment: its perfectly legit to post a well formatted answer to your own question and then accept it as the answer after 48 hrs. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks Shellter, the only issue is that I dont have great technical knowledge. I posted what helped me. Tried to find the right answer to elaborate on it more, but could'nt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was with my RVM Installation.

To fix it just add:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session as a function
```

to your ~/.bash_profile

(I do not have the technical knowledge to post the reasons, sorry.)